# Is it possible, in CSS, to rearrange a table WITHOUT creating gaps?

Tags: css

Thoroughly expecting a no but I figured I'd ask before I give up.

I *cannot* edit the site itself. I can only edit how the site *displays in my browser* with CSS.

I'm trying to rearrange a table so that it takes up half the height and double the width. So far the best I've got is the following:

```
 tr:nth-child(odd) {
     transform: translateY(-170px) translateX(603px)
 }
```

Where the Y-translation is exactly euqal to the table's current height, and the X-translation is equal to the table's current width. Neither of those change beyond about 5px as the content's width and height is always the same.

If you repeat the non-header trs in the sample table, the issue becomes clearer; but even with just the header it's apparent that there's a 170px gap between each (CSS-created) row, effectively meaning I haven't changed a thing. The whole point of this exercise is to halve the amount of scrolling I have to do.

So I suppose my questions are:

1) Is there a cleaner way to forcibly rearrange a table using nothing but CSS?

2) Or, is there a way to remove that gap? I've tried things like negative margins and moving select elements up/down but the issue persists no matter what I do. That gap is stubborn.

A sample of the table in question:

````
<tbody><tr>
  <th colspan="4">Table Header</th>
</tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="100x100px-exactly.png" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td> 

    </tr>

 </tbody></table>```
````

Comment: can you update the `width`, `height`, and `border-collapse`?

Comment: @Ibu Sadly `border-collapse: collapse` doesn't help and I can't define a fixed height for the table as items are often added/removed.

Comment: do you have access to the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Half the height and double the width, based on your sample table, seems like you want to turn 2 table rows into one.  If that's true you may want to play with the `display` property for `tr` and `td` and then adjust the other items as needed.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

tbody tr:not(:first-child) {
  display: inline;
}

td {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80px;
}

.item {
  font-size: 8px;
}

.thumb {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Table Header</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="bottom">
        <span class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" class="thumb"><br>
          Description</span><br>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```